# Context.drawImage cropping a small image onto a large canvas causes antialias from outside the crop rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying to crop an image using the `context.drawImage` cropping parameters when I ran into an odd behavior. A simplified image looks like below where I was trying to crop away the 1px blue outline.

[image: original image]

```
context.drawImage(image, 1, 1, 30, 30, 9, 9, 32, 32);
```

This correctly drew the cropped image on a canvas of < 250px wide/tall. However, when I increased the size of the canvas to more than 300px, the result looked like this:

[image: image rendered in chrome]

Moving the image just slightly shows the problem better (the above image just barely has the blue around it, can be hard to see).

[image: image rendered in chrome]

For some reason, the blue outline now shows with antialiasing. I didn't change the drawImage code, only the size of the canvas.

Is this expected behavior or a bug <strike>in Chrome (doesn't happend in Firefox or Safari)</strike>? I know turning off antialiasing will remove the blue outline, but I'd rather not.

**EDIT**: Firefox and Edge on my PC have the same problem at any canvas size.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/straker/w4y9e4sv/)

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(image, 1, 1, 30, 30, 9.4, 9, 32, 32);
  };
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAtElEQVRYR+2XWw7AIAgE4f6Hpmkaa32hWBA/7AHccRqVRQAicPzwAUD0YSASAxABawwRBJsRAPSCc4NjIAMA0mAZSAfgb3iAadtgALTCeYgGgHZ4G6ICYBVeh9gNwHr3pYXMgCvAqvDUwsfAATgGjgF3A/f5XAURn+edbsJwQ1lbSIeT3V5DawvlaLbrSKZtYmoo1YLg+8FAL5gFUSsmedHoHdOx4LgtcTfULbHvL9BdVrLaBbs2z+GYw+/7AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
```

```css
canvas {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: can't repro on chrome 51 on mac, but why `9.4` ?

Comment: Hu, I'm using chrome 51 on mac. 9.4 is just an arbitrary number. What I'm doing is moving the image across the screen at a non-integer rate (so like 0.2, etc.).

Comment: Then are you sure it doesn't come from the moving+erasing operation? Can you see it in your snippet?

Comment: Moving it only revealed the problem. I updated the post with code and an image of what it looks like when it's drawn to a whole number and you can still see the outline.